# U-Boot: Changing TTY columns and rows for virtual consoles

Tags: video, tty, u-boot

Having installed **GRUB** as boot manager allows the operating system (Linux) to boot on specific **video mode** so the TTY virtual consoles change its columns and rows (width and height).
For example, editing `/etc/default/grub` (for GRUB v2) :

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768
```

But now I have an **embedded Linux** device: [Utilite Pro](http://www.compulab.co.il/utilite-computer/web/utilite-pro-specifications) from CompuLab, and I am testing Ubuntu 12.04 and Kali Linux v1.1.1 for it.
They both work OK, but seem not to use GRUB as boot loader. According to the [docs](http://www.compulab.co.il/utilite-computer/wiki/index.php/Utilite_U-Boot), they use U-Boot as boot manager.

Could I do this **resolution** change for **virtual consoles** (TTY, text mode) for **U-Boot**?
I don't need to change the GUI video resolution, yet I can accept to change it too if it is needed.